# Querying for a set number of nodes for both parents and children in Neo4J

Tags: neo4j, cypher, relationship

Given the following data set:

```
(a)-[:PARENT]->(b)
(b)-[:PARENT]->(c)
(c)-[:PARENT]->(d)
(d)-[:PARENT]->(e)
(e)-[:PARENT]->(f)
(g)-[:PARENT]->(h)
(h)-[:PARENT]->(i)
```

I want to be able to traverse the graph both for parents as well as children from the "D" node and limit the number of hops done in the result set (i.e. I want to only go back and forwards two hops to get this data ending up from "B" through "H" nodes but ignoring all other generations).

Comment: Shouldn't the result be "b" through "f"?

Comment: I'm specifically looking for the hierarchy so that I can build a generational tree for a certain number of generations forwards and backwards.  For instance I want to see where I started (D) and it's parents, grandparents, children, and grandchildren and what path it took to get to them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this query do what you want? It assumes that all the nodes have an `id` property with a string value.

```
MATCH p=()-[:PARENT*..2]->(x)-[:PARENT*..2]->()
WHERE x.id = 'd'
WITH DISTINCT NODES(p) AS np
UNWIND np AS n
RETURN COLLECT(DISTINCT n.id)
```

The result, given your data, will be `["b","c","d","e","f"]`.

Comment: I think it's close - I'm fairly new to cypher so having to break away from traditional querying has been interesting.  I'll test it in a bit :)

Comment: It was close to what I was looking for.  I ended up splitting the hierarchy in two so that I could set the data up appropriately.